# Please vote for our “shining star” question in our Tour page!

Tags: discussion

The current Tour example question is perhaps not the best question to use as an example for our site.

[Here's the criteria on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163947/300411). According to this criteria, the system picks a certain number of questions to allow to be showcased on the site. Currently, there are 10 in the list. Some of them are being rejected outright. The rest are going to be posted as answers to this question.

Please vote up or down for ones you feel would be good or bad candidates. If there's a reason to flat out reject one, please post a comment why. The answer with the most votes will be selected to be our "shining star" in the tour.

It's important to keep in mind while voting to consider *answers* as well as questions. Be sure to consider the *answers and the question together* that will appear in the tour.

Comment: The vast majority of our questions require opinion-based answers. I get why that kind of thing is discouraged, but that's what we have here. Choosing fact-centered topics for the tour page actually misrepresents what people will find at SQA.

Comment: I've set the one with the most votes as the tour question. Hurra!

Answer (score 9):

[How can I reduce the execution speed in webdriver so that I can view properly what is happening on browser?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/8451/65)

> I want to reduce the speed for execution of script so that I can view the execution properly on browser. I want do this in webdriver.

Answer (score 5):

[What is exact difference between TDD and BDD?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15551/what-is-exact-difference-between-tdd-and-bdd)

> What is exact difference between TDD and BDD? Could you please briefly explain them to me?

Comment: This one can't be in the tour, because all of the answers have too much formatting and/or are too long.  See the criteria link in the question.

Comment: the questions I listed aren't ones I came up with, log_file. They're the ones the system will let me choose. Since this question isn't in the list the system gave me, we can't choose it.

Answer (score 4):

Our current question:

[When can we say a product is stable?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/15353/65)

> From a tester's point of view when do we say that a product is stable?
>
> Is the product still stable when it contains a known bug?

Comment: This question is pretty opinion-based.  Plus, right now [this](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/15379/15548) and [this](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/15356/15548) would be the answers that appear, due to length and formatting of the other more highly voted answers, and they don't look ideal.

Answer (score 4):

[Is there some software to document the results of functional software testing?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/1794/65)

> Can anyone recommend some software that can be used to document the results of functional software testing?
>
> This is not at developer level, it is for testers to follow documented procedures/scripts and then document what they find. I thought there must be some common tools that people use for this.

Answer (score 1):

[What test management tool to manage Cucumber tests?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/2095/65)

> In my company we have our tests specified in Gherkin (Cucumber), and we use Jenkins to schedule the execution of these tests.
>
> We have the need of a management tool, where we can associate the tests to the requirements and have the reports. Are there some tools that read the Cucumber feature files?

Answer (score 1):

[Tools for testing iPhone apps](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/1161/65)

> I was wondering if there any automation tools out there that can help with the process of testing an iPhone application on the device itself and not on a simulator.
>
> Ideally, it would have simulating button clicks, selections, and general alphanumeric input (sort of like how selenium can be used with web browsers).

Comment: The best answers to this question are all too long or have too much formatting.

Answer (score 1):

[Do ISTQB/ISEB Testing Certificates prove that someone can test?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/1055/65)

> I have passed the foundation level exam, and to be honest, I'm pretty sure that anyone could pass that exam with a couple of days of studying. My question is are these certificates really of value to my career and should I put any effort into acquiring the more advanced levels?

Comment: This questions have answers which are opinion based. Also the ones which have the highest votes [this](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/1058/15319) and [this](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/1070/15319) are not really ideal

Comment: @Minion4 the answer you linked doesn't meet criteria for being shown (too long) so no need to worry about that.

Comment: My bad..I forgot the <400 criteria. Thanks @corsika.
But the ones which are indeed <400 are opinionated too.

Comment: You'll find that to be the case with many <400 answers, actually. It can be very difficult to find good, short answers. Hence why this question exists to weed them all out. :)

Answer (score 1):

[What are the forms of testing that testers commonly forget?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/517/what-are-the-forms-of-testing-that-testers-commonly-forget)

> Today I re-realized the importance of sharing a screen with your users to see exactly what they're doing and the paths they are taking through your software.
>
> I always knew it was important but never thought of it as a way of testing beta software. Users will often come up with ways of doing stuff that you never thought of.
>
> So in my realization of this today I pose the question of; What are the forms of testing that testers commonly forget?

Answer (score 1):

[Testing email generation](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/testing-email-generation)

> Some applications generate emails. There may be multiple email formats based on the purpose of the message. The email may be destined for a single individual or a group. It may also be locale-dependent.
>
> What are some useful techniques for automating testing emails?

Answer (score 0):

[Alternatives to HP Quality Center for small business](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/2554/65)

> Which are the alternatives today? Not only freeware, but tools affordable for a development team of 3-5 men.
>
> I like the structure and flexibility of HP QC, so a similar tool would be nice to have.

Comment: This is really a list question, and most of the answers are suggestions and/or opinions.

Comment: I would downvote this if I could, but alas I can't vote on my own posts. : )

Answer (score 0):

[Are state transition diagrams a good software testing technique](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/907/65)

> I have been looking at different testing techniques and wondered if anyone had some "real world" examples of using state transition diagrams rather than the bog standard clock and light switch ones that are always used. I was also wondering if when using a wizard does each page of the wizard count as a separate state?

Comment: This question has answers which are too long and the ones which are <400 characters are opinion based.